# How to rename parent's fieldname

Tags: django, django-models

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    ...

class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  ...
  ...

class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    //i want groups rename to roles

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

i see the migrations has RenameField , how to use? the code is very clear, why the system always prompts for more details, idiot system.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=16)

    groups = AbstractUser._meta.get_field('groups')
    groups.db_column = 'roles'
    groups.name = 'roles'
```